# Laravel 5 get route prefix in controller method

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working in Laravel 5.0 app.

I have created route group like below,

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'expert'], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard', [
          'as'   => 'expert.dashboard',
          'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'
    ]);
 ]);
```

I want to get the current route prefix in `DashboardController`'s `index` method.
I dont know how to do that. I could not find this in documentation. Please help me.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do this two way

Type-hinting `Request` in method

```
 public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
  dd($request->route()->getPrefix());
 }
```

or

```
 public function index(){
  dd($this->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute()->getPrefix());
 }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The second variant no longer seems to work with Laravel 5.3

Comment: What if we have multiple prefixes? like patient/{xyz}

Comment: Route::prefix('{any}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        dd(request()->route('any'));
    });
});

Comment: @AttilaFulop its may but working with Laravel 6 as well

Answer (score 3):

```
Request()->route()->getPrefix()
```

Comment: please explain more or write the exact code that the asker needs to get his problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

To get your dynamic route's value after using

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => '{param}'], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard', [
          'as'   => 'expert.dashboard',
          'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'
    ]);
 ]);
```

You can simply use on your controller

```
public function index($param) {
    dump($param);
  
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
$request = Request();
$request->route()->group;
```

Comment: This is an error please check your code