# Passing variable to controller from route

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v3/page1'], function()
{
    Route::get('page1', 'TestController@page1');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'v4/page1'], function()
{
    Route::get('page1', 'TestController@page1');
});
```

As you can see, there are 2 groups that have the same routes. The only difference is that the prefix is slightly different for each group.

I need a way to pass data from route to controller. In this case Im only interested in passing the "v3" or "v4"-string from route to controller.

I have read a little about before_filter. But Im not sure if it is the right way to go.
I can imagine that a solution could be to extract the url (maybe in the constructor for the controller) and from there understand if the prefix is v3 or v4. But I wonder if there is a better way, more a best practice. Maybe something with before_filter?

Comment: The answer for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113361/laravel-5-get-route-prefix-in-controller-method) is applicable to yours. Also you can remove the "/page1" part from your prefixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{version}/page1'], function(){
    Route::get('page1', 'TestController@page1');
})->where('version', 'v[3|4]');
```

In your controller you can get the version by `$request->version`

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{v}/page1'], function()
{
    Route::get('page1', 'TestController@page1');
});
```

& in your method

```
public function page1($v) {}
```

Read more from https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{version}'], function() 
{
    Route::get('page1', 'TestController@page1');
});
```

I wouldn't pass in 'page1' in prefix, as it would mean page1 will show up twice in route.
In 'page1($version)' method you should be able to get the version.
I haven't tested this though.