# Laravel.54 pass data to action controller

Tags: laravel

I need to get 'mp3' value in controller !
( to check posts from `mp3s type` )

my post types : 
video, album , mp3

(web.php)

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'mp3s'), function($pt) {
    Route::get("/", "PostController@archivePosts");
    Route::get("mp3/{slug}", "PostController@singlePost");
  });


Route::group(array('prefix' => 'albums'), function($pt) {
    Route::get("/", "PostController@archivePosts");
    Route::get("album/{slug}", "PostController@singlePost");
  });


Route::group(array('prefix' => 'videos'), function($pt) {
    Route::get("/", "PostController@archivePosts");
    Route::get("video/{slug}", "PostController@singlePost");
  });
```

Comment: why not just use Route::get("{prefix}/{slug}", "PostController@singlePost"); ?

Comment: did you mean like you want to get slug value in controller's function?

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia i can get slug

Comment: @KoIIIeY - because . you may enter prefix as "test" in website and it's wrong, ( i was using middleware to detect prefix and i thought it's a wrong way )

Comment: @danialdezfooli you want to get prefix right ?

Comment: yes . mp3 or album or vidoe

Comment: or if you know a way to merge thesse to one route on right way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@danial dezfooli

To Get Prefix value you can inject Request Dependency inside controller's method as below.

```
public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
  dd($request->route()->getPrefix());
}

or you can do in another way also


public function index(){
  dd($this->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute()->getPrefix());
 }
```

For more reference you can refer : [Laravel 5 get route prefix in controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113361/laravel-5-get-route-prefix-in-controller-method)

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get("mp3/{slug}", "PostController@singlePost");
```

In PostController, you can get it like

```
    public function singlePost($slug) {
       dd($slug)// to check slug value
    }
```